# Windows IOT C#/Xaml BitmapImage Compiler Error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I'm getting the following compiler error and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
Error CS0246    The type or namespace name 'BitmapImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm using C#/Xaml on Windows IoT on a raspberry Pi 3. I'm guessing I'm missing a reference but I can't seem to figure out what reference to add(see list of references in image below).  It's not recognizing Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.

The line of code triggering the compiler error is this:

```
 PictureFrame.Source = new BitmapImage(new 
    Uri("/MyNameSpace;images/someimage.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

[image]

Comment: I think your development environment is broken. Have you tried to reinstall the visual studio? [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage) is included in [Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging) namespace,it is in Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.dll assembly.

Comment: There is no specific check items you have to tick.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue after reinstall the visual studio?